# nodejs, background-image css doesn't work

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

quick and simple question, I'm trying to add a div with a background-image in *.ejs page file.

```
<style>
    .signPage{
        background-image: url("//back.jpg");
        width: 98%;
        height: 98vh;
        top: 1%;
        right: 1%;
        position: fixed;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
```

the image and the ejs are in the same directory.
thanks

Comment: Just try `background-image: url("./back.jpg");`

Comment: i tried before still not working for me, tried also full path and not working c:/.../back.jpg

Comment: your public folder/directory name.

background-image: url("dirName/back.jpg");

Comment: What does node have to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to first provide a static path in app.js and then put background image at public/images 
to use it just

```
background-image: url("images/back.jpg");
```

`app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));`

Answer (score 0):

> You have to provide the path from the css file in which you have
> specified the rule.
>  For example: if the image is in folder
> public/images
>  and the css file is in folder public/css,
>  then you
> should provide like this
> -- ../images/image-name.image-extension

In short - You have to provide a path relative to css to image